# Why pynput doesn't detect numeric keyboard presses?

Tags: python, keyboard, detection

I'm using python 3.7 on windows 7.

Is there any way to detect number (for example: "1") key presses in pynput module?

I have tried many other modules and i got nothing except for tkinter
which needs a window but i don't want that.

```
from pynput import keyboard  
def on_press(key):
     print(key)
     if str(format(key)) == 'Key.1':
         print('Exiting...')
         return False 
with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

It actually only prints the pressed key and never brakes(doesn't accept the numeric input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided seems to be trying to detect Numeral key '1' rather than 'Num lock'.

@BoarGules has provided a complete answer. Just to add a bit of clarification:

When you monitor keyboard using pynput, if trying to detect a control key, you should compare it with appropriate pynput.keyboard.Key object. In case of checking for num lock, your code should look like this:

```
if key == keyboard.Key.num_lock:
    print('exiting')
```

On the other hand, if you're looking for an alpha-numeric key, compare it with pynput.keyboard.KeyCode:

```
if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char = '1'):
    print('exiting')
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is testing for the value `"1"`. This is, your pardon for stating the obvious, what `pynput` returns if you press the `1` key. You want to respond to the `NumLock` key.

Instead of

```
if str(format(key)) == '1':
```

you can code either of these tests, both of which check for the value you are looking for:

```
if key == keyboard.Key.num_lock:

if str(format(key)) == "Key.num_lock":
```

But... There are two kinds of `NumLock` key.

One is *Keyboard NumLock and Clear* which has both a USB code (0x53) and a Windows virtual key code (0x90). `pynput` will respond to pressing this key.

The other kind is *Keyboard Locking NumLock* which works at the keyboard level: it changes the way your keyboard behaves, and Windows doesn't get to hear about it. It has a USB code (0x83), but it doesn't have a Windows virtual key code. If there is no virtual key code for the key, there won't be a Windows message for pressing it, and `pynput` reports Windows messages.

So the behaviour is hardware-dependent and it may be that your machine has the second kind of `NumLock` key. If it does, then nothing you can say to `pynput` will help. This is unlikely, though, unless you are working with a very restricted laptop keyboard.

Comment: then what should i write instead of that ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the [doc](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.num_lock) shows that the num lock key may be undefined on some platforms. I don't have a windows machine to test this on unfortunately.

> ```
> num_lock = <Key.f1: 0>
> ```
>
> The NumLock key. This may be undefined for some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Testing all the returns I realized that there is a key.vk function that returns the code of each key. Number 1 on the numerical keyboard returned the value 97.
So by adding this comparison you can include the numeric keyboard:

```
if str(key) == '<97>': # 97 means number 1
```